# int-jpa:retrieving-outbound-gateway and caching the result

Tags: spring-data, spring-integration

IS it possible to cache the result of jap retriving oubound gateway(int-jpa:retrieving-outbound-gateway). So that every time the query is not executed if result available in cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution with existing code base may look like:

```
<transformer input-channel="input" ref="testBean" method="upperCase" output-channel="output">
    <request-handler-advice-chain>
        <cache:advice>
            <cache:caching cache="foo">
                <cache:cacheable method="handle*Message" key="#a0.payload"/>
            </cache:caching>
        </cache:advice>
    </request-handler-advice-chain>
</transformer>
```

It is `<transformer>` here, but the same is applied for the JPA gateway as well.

Pay attention to the `method="handle*Message"` AOP path.
Plus the `key` expression is based on the `Message` as `a0` `cacheable` Advice argument.

That's may be why we still don't support it as out-of-the box component in Spring Integration. Pretty simple and straightforward solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently provided by the framework, but you can easily add a [custom advice](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain) to the outbound gateway to implement this mechanism.